# How can I fix regression model interpretation of feature?

Tags: python, regression, multivariate-distribution

I'm building a regression model to predict the values of a feature $Y$ given a set of other features $X_{1}, X_{2}, X_{3}..X_{n}$.

Onde of these other features, let's say $X_1$, is known to be inversely proportional to $Y$ based on domain's knowledge. The problem is my model is interpreting his coefficient as positive, letting it directly proportional to $Y$. I've tried plenty of different models to verify if I could get better interpretation, such as OLS, Linear Regression, and Logistic Regression, but every model I tried failed to interpret the $X_1$ coefficient.

What can I do to get a regression that better reflects the real-world behavior of this coefficient?

Comment: so u expect the coef of X1 to be negative because it is inversely proportional to Y?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: How can I achieve that?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "$X_1$ is known to be inversely proportional to $Y$"?  Univariate analysis, domain knowledge, theoretical fact, ...?

Comment: It's only domain knowledge. I'm working on a model to make some prediction scenarios. One of these scenarios consists of raising the values of $X_{1}$. I expect $Y$ to go down, but $Y$ raises too, which in the domain of the features is wrong behaviour.

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/73666/232706

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless there's a mistake in your code, or the coefficient on $X_1$ is not significant, I'd be inclined to trust the model output.

It's not unusual for data to behave this way. Just because $X_1$ and $Y$ are inversely related with respect to the marginal distribution of $(X_1, Y)$, as can be concluded from a scatterplot of the two variables, does not mean this relationship holds *conditional* on other variables.

Here is an example where $(X_1, Y)$ are inversely related, but are positively related conditional on another value, $X_2$. (The example is generated using R -- you've tagged python, but this concept is language-agnostic):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
set.seed(1)
N <- 100
dat <- tibble(
    x2 = sample(1:4, size = N, replace = TRUE),
    x1 = x2 + rnorm(N) / 3,
    y = x1 - 2 * x2 + rnorm(N) / 5
)
ggplot(dat, aes(x1, y)) +
    geom_point(aes(colour = factor(x2))) +
    theme_bw() +
    scale_colour_discrete("x2")
```

[image]

Here are the outputs of a linear regression model. You'll notice that the coefficient on $X_1$ is negative when $X_2$ is not involved, as anticipated, but is positive when $X_2$ is involved. That's because the interpretation of a regression coefficient is the relationship *given* the other covariates.

```r
lm(y ~ x1, data = dat) %>% 
    tidy()
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)   -0.492    0.154      -3.20 1.83e- 3
#> 2 x1            -0.809    0.0549    -14.7  1.33e-26
lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = dat) %>% 
    tidy()
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)   0.0189    0.0540     0.349 7.28e- 1
#> 2 x1            1.04      0.0681    15.3   1.42e-27
#> 3 x2           -2.05      0.0726   -28.2   1.60e-48
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

This concept extends to more than two covariates, as well as continuous covariates.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightening answer. I will give a better look for the other features and verify how can I better use then to get the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

**The model can only see the data** provided for training. Not the domain truth.

1. *Is your Y inversely proportional to X1* 

  - Check with a simple scatterplot

  - Also, try to see the correlation strength(with Y) with a correlation matrix

2. *If No*, 

  - Check the data source and understand the conflict

3. *if Yes*,

Possible cause can be the impact of any other variable(pointed in the accepted answer), you can try these - 

  - **Forward selection**, build a model with X1 and see the coef_, must be -ve and then add other variables one by one and see which variable does this

 - Check the Correlation with other variables, X1 might be a less important feature. This might give you a new insight to look into in your data and domain